# Restrict user from executing shell commands using PHP

Tags: php, server

Let's say that i have shared hosting and i want to secure that place, from executing shell commands. I'v installed suphp, so that users can execute PHP separately. I also did some other things in order to protect server (basedir and other recommended settings inside php.ini).

But the problem is still there: (i can execute and read config files from other websites)

```
<?php echo exec('cat /var/www/website/config.php'); ?>
```

If i disable exec function, still there are other ways to find out sensitive information from the server.

What can i do? Can i disable unix shell commands for specific user, will that take effect?

**Edit: I'v changed premission on bin 754, before it was 755, and now users are unable to run shell commands using PHP. Is this a solution or not?**

Comment: I think I understand now -- you are the admin on a shared web host and want to prevent users from being able to view files owned by other users?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable exec and suexec, enable open_basedir and basically follow every suggestion in [this post](http://www.madirish.net/199).

You mentioned `still there are other ways to...` if after reading that post you still have questions or weaknesses, please post them here or in Serverfault

Comment: why not? All these are good suggestions

Answer (score 1):

> I'v changed premission on bin 754, before it was 755, and now users are unable to run shell commands using PHP.

I think, this is interesting solution. But separation of security rules is not convenient for specific users in this case.

I would like to suggest few other ways:

1. Run apache as `chroot`. But it requires complex configuring.
   It allows to create "isolated" execution-space for each virtual host (execution user).
   In my opinion, good example described here: [Apache + Chroot + FastCGI + PHP FAQ](http://www.seaoffire.net/fcgi-faq.html)
2. Run apache and php inside Docker container. It is more modern solution for vhost isolation. But it requires complex configuring too.
3. Disable potentially unsafe functions via [`disable_functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) directive in `php.ini`. This is more simple and less safe way. For example:

   `disable_functions=dl,system,exec,passthru,shell_exec,stream_select,popen,proc_open,proc_nice,ini_set`

Potentially unsafe functions may be found here: [Functions restricted/disabled by safe mode](http://php.net/safe-mode.functions).